# Preprocessor invalid preprocessor token error

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am reading a book to learn **C**. In that book is the following example code giving a preprocessor error with gcc (Debian 4.7.2-4) 4.7.2. The error is:

> file.c: In function ‘main’:
>       file.c:16:14: error: token ""I know the C language.\n"" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
>       file.c:20:14: error: token ""I know BASIC.\n"" is not valid in preprocessor expressions

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C_LANG    'C'
#define B_LANG    'B'
#define NO_ERROR  0

int main(void)
{
   #if C_LANG == 'C' && B_LANG == 'B'
     #undef C_LANG
     #define C_LANG "I know the C language.\n"
     #undef B_LANG
     #define B_LANG "I know BASIC.\n"
     printf("%s%s", C_LANG, B_LANG);
   #elif C_LANG == 'C'
     #undef C_LANG
     #define C_LANG "I only know C language.\n"
     printf("%s", C_LANG);
   #elif B_LANG == 'B'
     #undef B_LANG
     #define B_LANG "I only know BASIC.\n"
     printf("%s", B_LANG);
   #else
     printf("I don't know C or BASIC.\n");
   #endif

   return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Is the gcc preprocessor incapable of doing this correctly or is the something wrong with the code that needs to be changed?

Comment: I'm thinking it's the printfs that are messing things up.

Comment: No, it's the #elif lines that are having problems. For instance, the preprocessor is expanding the first #elif to `#elif "I know the C language.\n" == 'C'` and then failing on that. [ideone fails it too.](http://ideone.com/TkzvEk)

Comment: Either of the answers given so far will work. However, I must say, if this is an example from a book, you may want to reconsider what book you are using.

Comment: @cebarth: I think you are right. The book is Sam's Teaching yourself C in 24 hours. It was a great for bash scripting and got me well on my way years ago with that. This really helped me grasp pointers when the Apress book C: Novice to Professional had me stumped on them, but it is using Windows with an unknown compiler. Perhaps the preprocessor is "smarter" which makes me sad for gcc. This is the 23rd chapter and thus 1 more to go. I'll finish it, but will definately be reading other books, too.

Comment: So I'm guessing nothing is wrong with the code as c preprocessors in general aren't designed to understand `#if "foo" == "foo"` type evaluations? Perhaps just a peculularity of the preprocessor the author is using?

Comment: @narnie Instead of `#elif`, you could use `#else` (newline) `#if C_LANG == 'C'` ... `#endif`. clang compiles the code without so much as a raised eyebrow, gcc seems to have a different interpretation of the preprocessing phase.

Comment: @narnie I-am-not-a-C-guru but I would suggest that such preprocessor code isn't really common/desirable. I think it's strange that `gcc` seems to evaluate the conditional expression in the `elif` even when the previous `if` has been checked to be non-zero, but I would maybe suggest that this sort of edge case isn't important. I think if you ever wanted code like this you'd at least want to use two different macro definitions like BLUEPIXY suggests. Also, I think if the book stated clearly at the beginning that it was using a different compiler, that you can't _really_ fault it for that.

Answer (score 2):

As @cebarth points out, the problem is that after you redefined `C_LANG` and `B_LANG` in the first `#if`, the `#elif` clauses fail, because the expansion is:

```
   #elif "I know the C language.\n" == 'C'
   /*...*/
   #elif "I know BASIC.\n" == 'B'
```

The C Standard says this about `#if` and `#elif` (C99 6.10.1):

> Preprocessing directives of the forms
>   `# if constant-expression new-line groupopt`
>   `# elif constant-expression new-line groupopt`
>   check whether the controlling constant expression evaluates to nonzero.

There is no mention of not evaluating the expression because of an earlier check having succeeded.

One way to fix this is to redefine them back after the `printf()`.

```
     #undef C_LANG
     #define C_LANG "I know the C language.\n"
     #undef B_LANG
     #define B_LANG "I know BASIC.\n"
     printf("%s%s", C_LANG, B_LANG);
     #undef C_LANG
     #define C_LANG 'C'
     #undef B_LANG
     #define B_LANG 'B'
```

Another way to fix this is to explicitly use `#else` instead of `#elif`.

```
   #if C_LANG == 'C' && B_LANG == 'B'
     #undef C_LANG
     #define C_LANG "I know the C language.\n"
     #undef B_LANG
     #define B_LANG "I know BASIC.\n"
     fprintf(stdout, "%s%s", C_LANG, B_LANG);
   #else
     #if C_LANG == 'C'
       #undef C_LANG
       #define C_LANG "I only know C language.\n"
       printf("%s", C_LANG);
     #elif B_LANG == 'B'
       #undef B_LANG
       #define B_LANG "I only know BASIC.\n"
       printf("%s", B_LANG);
     #else
       printf("I don't know C or BASIC.\n");
     #endif
   #endif
```

Comment: Isn't the real question: Why does the preprocessor execute the `elif` code after the `if` succeeds?

Comment: I don't think it is executing it, but rather just parsing the line. Does seem a bit silly though.

Comment: @roliu: The C Standard says only that the `#if` and `#elif` expressions are evaluated, and doesn't give any exceptions just because some prior `#if` or `#elif` has already matched. I will update the answer.

Comment: "There is no mention of not evaluating the expression because of an earlier check having succeeded." - True, but [GCC does mention it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_4.html#SEC41). `"Then the text after each '#elif' is processed only if the '#elif' condition succeeds after the original '#if' and all previous '#elif' directives within it have failed"`

Comment: @Mike, I think the "text after" refers to the conditional block, not the expression itself (i.e. 'groupopt', not 'constant-expression' in C99 6.10.1 item 3)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C_LANG    'C'
#define B_LANG    'B'
#define NO_ERROR  0

int main(void)
{
   #if C_LANG == 'C' && B_LANG == 'B'
     #define C_LANG_VALUE "I know the C language.\n"
     #define B_LANG_VALUE "I know BASIC.\n"
     printf("%s%s", C_LANG_VALUE, B_LANG_VALUE);
   #elif C_LANG == 'C'
     #define C_LANG_VALUE "I only know C language.\n"
     printf("%s", C_LANG_VALUE);
   #elif B_LANG == 'B'
     #define B_LANG_VALUE "I only know BASIC.\n"
     printf("%s", B_LANG_VALUE);
   #else
     printf("I don't know C or BASIC.\n");
   #endif

   return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally mixing preprocessor code and non-preprocessor code is not a good idea because it's hard to follow the execution path (well, most times).

For your particular example there is something you can do to make things easier:

```
#define C_LANG 
#define B_LANG  
#define NO_ERROR

#if defined(C_LANG) || defined (B_LANG)
   #if defined(C_LANG)
       printf ("I know the C language.\n");
   #else
       printf ("I know the BASIC language.\n");
   #endif
#else
   printf("I don't know C or BASIC.\n");
#endif
```

No need to use macro definitions. You can change what is printed out by simply adding one character to eiter C_LANG or B_LANG:

```
#define C_LANGn
#define B_LANGn
```

This way the code is much more readable.